# Django QueryDict List Format

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use a checkbox form that takes in any number of selections from a dropdown checkbox. I am having trouble in getting my POST data to be formatted correctly..

Right now, I have it formatted as:

```
<QueryDict: {u'application_picker': [u'', u'App1', u'App2', u'App3']}>
```

I want it formatted as: (a single value of all the apps seperated by spaces)

```
<QueryDict: {u'application_picker': [u'App1 App2 App3']}>
```

In my  **Forms.py**:

```
    def clean_application_picker(self): 
        application_picker = self.data.getlist('application_picker')
        return application_picker
```

*the piece of software I am using: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started

#### *My question: How to convert the many QueryDict values of the application_picker key to one long value that contains all the previous values but seperated by spaces?*

Comment: Why do you need this in the querydict itself? Why not in the clean method, where you can easily use Python's `join()` method to do it?

Comment: Inside forms.py underneath the clean method.... application_picker = " ".join(application_picker)     --- This worked!